# Modeling a neural net for inputs with varying properties

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm looking to use Tensorflow to set up a neural network to score items based on various properties they have. The amount of properties a given item can have is small (let's say 10 is the max) but the amount of possible properties is in the hundreds. For example, imagine we were scoring different kinds of vehicle, each with various attributes ("wheels", "engine horsepower", "wings", etc.) and a numerical value for that attribute (2, 600, 4).

My question is: is there a way to model the neural network for this to have a relatively low number of inputs, on the order of the max number of properties the item can have (in this example, 10)? Or does each possible property need to be an input, resulting in hundreds of total inputs, most of which (>90%) would be blank for any given item?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to have a large number of inputs, or are you just trying to figure out what the options are?

Comment: A larger number of inputs means longer training time and more complexity, but it seems necessary here. I'm very new to this, though, so mostly I'm just wondering about the options.

Answer (score 0):

Just have all of the possible properties as inputs, but set them to 0 when they are not present. Hundreds of inputs to a NN is not uncommon anyways.